AVR C code gets compiled successfully but in arduino ide it gives me error of missing functions
so i'm trying to call a c function in a c file in arduino uno.
using the gcc-avr command it gets compiled successfully:
sudo avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o nrf nrf.c

but on arduino ide, it gives me error of missing functions that the nrf.c is calling which exist in other c files. so how to fix it?
.ino file
#include "nrf.c"

extern "C" // these functions does not exist in c file they are in a .s file
{
    void init_serial();
    void print_msg();
    void light();
}
//----------------------------------------------------
void setup()
{
}

void loop(){
    nrf_start1();
    light();
}

this is the arduino ide's output:
/tmp/arduino/sketches/8589FEB308F7EAA6CFEF4682C1500C77/sketch/sketch_jul11a.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `nrf_start1()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_1'
/tmp/arduino/sketches/8589FEB308F7EAA6CFEF4682C1500C77/sketch/nrf.c.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/arduino/sketches/8589FEB308F7EAA6CFEF4682C1500C77/sketch/sketch_jul11a.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `nrf_start1()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `message_received'
/tmp/arduino/sketches/8589FEB308F7EAA6CFEF4682C1500C77/sketch/nrf.c.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/arduino/sketches/8589FEB308F7EAA6CFEF4682C1500C77/sketch/sketch_jul11a.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `nrf_start1()':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `status'

i tried to call the compiled one using extern c but it did not work

Post the code directly in the question, not off-site links.  Post the error message or complete build log too. You have only posted the build command for the successful build - which tells us nothing useful.

#include "nrf.c"- unless you know exactly what you're doing and have a good reason to do so, this is almost certainly wrong

@Clifford That wasn't a "build command for a successful build". It ws a compile command for a successful compile.

@tofro - Even if that were the case, it does not change the issue that it is not useful information. However the -o nrf makes it a compile and link.

No. The "-c" tells gcc to only compile. The "-o" only changes the name of the output (object) file to something misleading in this case. The OP's assumption that the gcc build succeeded is wrong.

@tofro ok - missed that in the narrow view afforded by my phone.  The point still stands. But the edit shows it to be a little linker error in any case - so it still compiles in Arduino.

@Clifford Yes, it's obviously a link failure. GCC didn't try to link at all, so the failure wasn't present there.

@tofro the original GitHub link was to code that included a main() so was also clearly not the code in question either.

You have now omitted the code nrf.c altogether.  Needs to be the actual code too.  Not code that is similar to the code you are asking about.  Also the error messages say nothing about "missing functions" as you stated.


Don't (ever) #include .c files. That's wrong in 99.9% of cases
You need to tell the Arduino IDE that your sketch contains more files than the single .ino. You do that by copying your "nrf.c" file to where your sketch lives and use "Sketch"->"Add File...". The Arduino IDE should now know that your Sketch consists of multiple files and generate appropriate linker commands. From your question, it is not clear to me if you did that already or not.
If you happen to have an additional ".S" file (not entirely clear from your question), do the same with that (but note, on some OSs, the IDE wants to see such files with an explicit upper-case "S" to recognize them as assembly source.


From the linker error messages and the code.  It is clear that you have both included nrf.c  and separately compiled and linked it.  I think the Arduino IDE automatically does that simply by adding the source to the sketch.
